# How to pass struct array into a function and correctly store value in it?

Tags: c

I would like to read a file that has the sample number, values and status(1.1, 23,0). I used a Struct to hold that information. I will pass the function struct array and the file location.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Data_point
{
    long sampleNumber;
    double value;
    int status;
};


int filldata(struct Data_point *a, const char *filelocation)
{
    FILE *f;
    if((f=fopen(filelocation,"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("You cannot open");
    }
    fscanf(f, "%ld%lf%d", a.sampleNumber, a.value, a.status);
}



int main(void)
{
    struct Data_point data[10];
    filldata(data, "/home/alexchan/IntrotoC/rec11/dataPoints.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

But, I got an error saying, "request for member not a structure"...

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says, and indicates the line where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, i wouldn't come to ask if i already know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try reading it? Do you know what a "member" is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that the `filldata()` is taking a pointer argument.  So you use `->` to address members not ".".  So `a.sampleNumber` should be `a->sampleNumber` for example.

Another issue is that `filldata()` is reading in a single struct, but you are passing it the pointer to the top of the array, which is synonymous with `&(data[0])`.  So this function will just overwrite that first element if you call it repeatedly (which you didn't).  If you call it in a loop you will need to pass it in pointers to the individual array members:

`for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  filldata(&(data[i]), "/home/alexchan/IntrotoC/rec11/dataPoints.txt");
}`

You could actually use `data + i` as the first arg instead of `&(data[i])` but I like the latter as I find it more readable.

Comment: But i am using fscanf, so i think i should be using the address? 
a->xxx is the value in member xxx isn't it?
Yes, i am just trying single struct for just now

Comment: Sorry you are correct.  You should pass `&(a->xxx)` as the args to scanf.

Comment: but that wouldn't make sense(and it didn't work)
&(a->xxx) means &(*a.xxx)

Comment: No.  `a` is a pointer.  So it cannot be followed by a dot.  &(a->xxx) is synonymous with &((*a).xxx).  In what way did it not work?

Comment: Oops sorry didn't see the asterisk in your comment above.  Can you explain what went wrong?

Comment: I try 
&a[0].xxx and it works.
But i am very confusing.
When i passed a int to a function and i do this
FUnction(int *a)
scanf("%d", a);  

but this situation require an extra & , isn't a mean the address already?

Comment: &a[0].xxx should work.  The bracket operator here is synonymous with an offset and a dereference, so it's the same as saying &((*(a+0)).xxx)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10032/discussion-between-michael-daum-and-qwr-qwr)

Comment: Ya, but i am confused because scanf request the address of the pointer pointed to.
int f(int * arr)
in this case we would use only scanf("%d", arr) to do so, why when we dealing with struct it becomes entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

struct Data_point *a is your function arugument and you are passing data which is a array. So basically you are trying to acess members from a array which is not a struct.

May be

```
for( int i=0; i<10;++i)
    filldata(data[i],.....)
```

and

```
int filldata( struct Data_point a,...) //as you are using a.
```

Comment: The way to address members of a struct would be the arrow operator (`->`).  I'm not entirely sure what you're accomplishing with `filldata(data[i], ...)`; did you mean to address the `data` array?

Comment: array itself contains address information isn't it? So i am passing the data, which is the first element of the array address,

Answer (score 0):

fscanf requires a pointer-to-data for each passed argument. Use the `AddressOf` operator `&` to get a reference to each struct member:

```
int filldata(const char *filelocation, struct Data_point *a, int nElements)
{
    int n = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen(filelocation, "r");
    if(f)
    {
        while (fscanf(f, "(%ld,%lf,%d)", &(a[n].sampleNumber), &(a[n].value), &(a[n].status)) == 3 && n < nElements)
             n++;
        fclose(f);
    } 
    else { printf("Unable to open '%s'\n", filelocation); }
    return n;
}
```

Now, this function is slightly different to yours. You need to tell it how long the array you're passing in as the "a" parameter is. It will return the number of successfully filled entries.

i.e

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct Data_point data[10];
    int n = filldata("C:\\Users\\254288b\\temp.txt", data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(struct Data_point));
    printf("%d Data_point's were filled successfully.\n\n", n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Sample Number: %ld\n", data[i].sampleNumber);
        printf("Value: %lf\n", data[i].value);
        printf("Status: %d\n", data[i].status);
        printf("----------------------------\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do note, my pattern for fscanf expects your file to be like:

`(100,1.1,10)(200,2.2,20)(300,3.3,30)(400,4.4,40)`

Each set is enclosed in parenthesis.